# Add screenshots to XUNIT test results from Robot framework to Azure Pipelines test tab

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework, azure-pipelines, xunit

Is there an easy way to link screenshots from XUNIT style test results generated by Robot Framework and loading them in to the Test tab via the Publish Test Results task of Azure Pipelines?

Similar to they way how it is working with VSTS result files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is not an easy way to achieve above.

As a workaround, you can use [Create Test Result Attachment rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20result%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to update the screenshot as attachment to the test case.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

In order to use above create test result attachment rest api. You need to call [query test runs rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the `runId`

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?buildIds={buildIds}&buildDefIds={buildDefIds}&api-version=5.1`

Then you will need to call list [test results rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the `testCaseresultId`

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.1`

So you can add a script task in your pipeline to run above rest apis. See below example:

```
- powershell: |  
    $url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/test/runs?buildIds=1417&buildDefIds=8&api-version=5.1"
    $runs = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get
    $runId = $runs.value[-1].id
    
    #get testCaseresultId
    $resuilturl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/test/Runs/$($runId)/results?api-version=5.1"
    $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $resuilturl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get
    #for example get first testCaseresultId 
    $testCaseResultId = $results.value[0].id
   
    #create test result attachment.
    $atturl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/test/Runs/$($runId)/Results/$($testCaseResultId)/attachments?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

    $body='{
             "stream": "VXNlciB0ZXh0IGNvbnRlbnQgdG8gdXBsb2FkLg==",
             "fileName": "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/screenshot-1.png",
             "comment": "Test attachment upload",
             "attachmentType": "GeneralAttachment"
           }'
     
   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $atturl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method post -Body $body
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me what path should I give in my code to save the screenshot? like I am giving this  string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + TestCaseName + ".png";